# Nodes can't be looked up by label in noe4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm having a problem where my labeled nodes don't seem to be found when I call

```
Iterable<Node> users = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodesWithLabel(DynamicLabel.label("User"));
```

However, when I call the following, I get the expected results:

```
Iterable<Node> allNodes = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes();
for(Node node : allNodes) {
   if (node.hasLabel(DynamicLabel.label("User")) {    
      found++;
   }
}
```

I'm wondering whether the index for labels may be corrupt?  Is there any way of rebuilding it? I'm using version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 2.0.4 (or 2.1.4) and check if the error persists. There have been a lot of bugfixes since 2.0.0.